# How does "distance" effect ambient occlusion?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, shaders, shadows, world

In Blender Cycles, there is a distance option for Ambient Occlusion in the World tab.
[image]
How does the distance option affect AO?  What does moving the distance closer to zero do?  What does increasing this value do?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/world.html?highlight=ambient%20occlusion